# Give an example of a sequence $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that $x_{nk}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $k \leq 2$

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a sequence $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that $x_{nk}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $k \leq 2$, whereas $x_n$ does not converge as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

How am I go about thinking of this? Or does that sequence even exist?

Comment: Take $k=1$. Then $nk=n$.

Comment: There is no such sequence.

Comment: Just as a guess... maybe $k\ge 2$ makes some sense. Then take $x_n$ to be zero if $n$ is not a prime, else $n$ or something ...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy why?

Comment: @spruce dan_fulea has already told you why.  If you have convergence for $k=1$ the you have convergence of $(x_n)$.